# Adding newlines in the middle of a sed substitute in a python script

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, sed

I am exploring a porting a big project from python 2 to 3.

Because I am presently just testing, and some other reasons. I change to change all

```
#!/usr/bin/python
or
#!/usr/bin/env python
or
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
```

to python3. In addition to this i wish to add two newlines and a comment. So that every python file that started with one of the above now starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# 4 spaces is the indentation standard. Make sure that Tab equals 4 spaces.
```

My current code will walk all directories and change python files one at a time and to this and several other changes. My problem is in the following function:

```
def usePy3_addcomment(filename):
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(['sed','-i.sedbak','s_#!/usr/bin/.*python.*_#!/usr/bin/env python3\n\n# 4 spaces is the indentation standard. Make sure that Tab equals 4 spaces._',filename]) 
    except:
        print("ERROR: usePy3_addcomment failed on '%s'" % filename)
    return None
```

The problem is in the \n. They are kept here to express what i wish to do. I've tried using the endline literal, using brackets and adding a\, but to no avail.

Error message is:

```
$sed: -e expression #1, char 48: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: You can try subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True) where cmd can be a working command on shell

Comment: @vks Thanks, but this produced the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `sed -ir 's:(#!/usr/bin/).*python.*:\1env python 3\n\n# Comment\n:'` in GNU/Linux Terminal and it worked fine. If you add [`find . -name "*.py" -exec`] before the `sed` command it should go through recursively, find all python files and apply the replacement.

Clearly Python is having troubling running the `\n` through `sed` so I would suggest running `sed` in an actual Terminal, unless you absolutely have to run it in Python. Let me know if this is the case and I'll attempt to do it through Python and not through Terminal.

Save the s/// part as `sed_script.sed`:

```
    s_#!/usr/bin/.*python.*_#!/usr/bin/env python3\n\n# 4 spaces is the indentation standard. Make sure that Tab equals 4 spaces._
```

Then run

```
    subprocess.call(['sed','-i','-f', "sed_script.sed",filename])
```

That should edit the `filename` using `sed_script.sed` and replace the parts you want

Comment: It didn't run in my terminal. Didn't like the parenthesis and exclamation marks needed to be backslashed. But that's beside the point. The sed command above runs in my terminal (with backslashed exclamation marks). And the problem is indeed that i wish to run it in python. 

What i wish to do is to run autopep8, 2to3 and my sed_function on one python file and then check bytecode equivalence with pydiff. I am not even sure if they will, or should, be bytecode-equivalent after this treatment, but other than, "i started doing this in python", this is my reason for running it in python.

Comment: From the python script:
    `$sed: -e expression #1, char 48: unterminated \`s' command`
with or without backslashed exclamationmarks.

Comment: It's likely due to the fact that `sed` normally reads the script within quotes, but because you're calling `sed` through `subprocess` the quoting is getting misinterpreted. Perhaps try saving the entire thing as a `sed` script and running that script instead of call the `sed` command. Or you can save the s/// part and use `sed -f` to call that file.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That worked, i would be nice to avoid the extra file, but oh well.

Comment: You could replaced the two `\n` with `=` in your original `sed` and then call `tr "=" "\n" filename` via `subprocess` after `sed`. I'm not sure how well that will work and I don't know the syntax of `subprocess`, but you can give it a try if you really don't want that extra file.